# Notifications are very delayed on android - but only sometimes (apparently FIXED)

Tags: notifications, 7.0-nougat

I searched for my problem but what I found either wasn't answered or was very old response and maybe things have changed since then...

I just got a Samsung Galaxy S8 and it's amazing, but maybe since yesterday notifications are a bit slow. I just answered and email that I got an hour ago from my computer while my phone still didn't show the notification. I got some test messages and again, they showed up but only after I opened up gmail app and refreshed it.

What might help find the answer - right now I'm spending most of the time on my computer when I have gmail website opened (for hangouts) and thunderbird for emails. However the days before I was mostly outside with my laptop either turned off of inactive.

Btw, I had a similar issue with the old phone (also android) but I just blamed it being 4 years old and acting up.

So what could be the possible issue? Some kind of setting on my phone? Possible network changes? (I changed cities in those days, maybe the network here sucks and phone tries to use it instead of wifi... I'm just looking for options here). Or is it just the fact that I have gmail / thunderbird opened?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around with more settings and a lot of online research and eventually I found this link:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1075549?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en

Apparently what I really had to do was go to
gmail app -> settings -> my account name
below notifications there's item "inbox - sound and vibration"
Turn "Notify about every message"

And that decreased the delay from hours (or never getting notifications) to 10 minutes maximum, with average time being 5 minutes.

I still don't know why this option would be off by default, seems like a very important thing. I am posting this in case someone else will have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to exclude Gmail app from the battery optimization setting: Go to Settings → Battery (or Power Manager) → select Battery optimization → search for Gmail and set as not optimizing battery use. This process might be different on newer versions of Android, I am using Marshmallow (Android 6).

And also in the new version of Gmail has a feature for notifying only for important messages and maybe it's turned on.